# RijndaelManaged false Decryption result

Tags: c#, encryption

i have a problem, i tried to fix it myself but i cant.
My program search als .txt files from a directory. Then it read the files and encrypt each file and overwrite the old file. That works fine. Now i want to decrypt the txt files, the following happens:

Here you can see the encrypted text and the decrypted text
[image]

So the Problem is, the .txt file becomes encrypted, and the decryption works too, but when i decrypt there dont come the original text. You can see it on the picture, there are coming only wired letters. I cant understand why, i use the same salt and the same password.

Here is my code:

The first 3 snippets are for encryption, the other 3 for decryption.

```
foreach (var file in d2.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName, file.Name);
    string temppfad = file.FullName;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(temppfad);
    string Inhalt = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(Inhalt + "\n");
    string Verschlüsselterinhalt = Verschlüsseln(Password, Inhalt);
    sr.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(temppfad, Verschlüsselterinhalt);
}
```

These Part is still working, just upload it to understand it better.

The encryption parts:

```
static string Verschlüsseln(string PW, string original)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        myRijndael.GenerateKey();
        myRijndael.GenerateIV();

        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0PQUX76U0adfaDADFexA888887Dz3J3X");
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PW, salt);
        myRijndael.Key = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.KeySize / 8);
        myRijndael.IV = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.BlockSize / 8);

        // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
        byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(original, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte item in encrypted)
        {
            s.Append(item.ToString("X2") + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted:   " + s + "\n\n");
        return s.ToString();
    }
}

static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    byte[] encrypted;
    // Create an RijndaelManaged object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {

                    //Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    return encrypted;
}
```

I think to that point all is ok, **now I will post the decryption parts.**

```
foreach (var file in d2.GetFiles("*.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName, file.Name);
    string temppfad = file.FullName;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(temppfad);
    string Inhalt = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine("Inhalt: " + Inhalt + "\n");
    string Entschlüsselterinhalt = Entschlüsseln(Password, Inhalt);
    sr.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(temppfad, Entschlüsselterinhalt);
}

static string Entschlüsseln(string PW, string original)
{
    using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        myRijndael.GenerateKey();
        myRijndael.GenerateIV();

        byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0PQUX76U0adfaDADFexA888887Dz3J3X");
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PW, salt);
        myRijndael.Key = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.KeySize / 8);
        myRijndael.IV = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.BlockSize / 8);

        // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
        byte[] originalbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original);
        string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(originalbytes, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

        //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
        Console.WriteLine("Decrypted:    " + decrypted);
        return decrypted;
    }
}

static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    // Check arguments.
    if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
    if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
    if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

    // Declare the string used to hold
    // the decrypted text.
    string plaintext = null;

    // Create an RijndaelManaged object
    // with the specified key and IV.
    using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
        rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {

                    // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                    // and place them in a string.
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

I would be very happy when someone could help me.

**UPDATE!!!**

I edited now my code, now it looks so:

```
                foreach (var file in d2.GetFiles("*.txt"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName, file.Name);
                    string temppfad = file.FullName;
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(temppfad);
                    string Inhalt = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(Inhalt + "\n");
                    byte[] Verschlüsselterinhalt = Verschlüsseln(Password, Inhalt);
                    sr.Close();
                    File.WriteAllBytes(temppfad, Verschlüsselterinhalt);
                }



    static byte[] Verschlüsseln(string PW, string original)
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0PQUX76U0adfaDADFexA888887Dz3J3X");
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PW, salt);
            myRijndael.Key = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.KeySize / 8);
            myRijndael.IV = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.BlockSize / 8);

            // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes(original, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);
            return encrypted;
        }
    }
```

I think that part is ok, now on decryption i get an **error**

```
                foreach (var file in d2.GetFiles("*.txt"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName, file.Name);
                    string temppfad = file.FullName;
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(temppfad);
                    string Inhalt = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine("Inhalt: " + Inhalt + "\n");
                    string Entschlüsselterinhalt = Entschlüsseln(Password, Inhalt);
                    sr.Close();
                    File.WriteAllText(temppfad, Entschlüsselterinhalt);
                }

   static string Entschlüsseln(string PW, string original)
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {

            byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("0PQUX76U0adfaDADFexA888887Dz3J3X");
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(PW, salt);
            myRijndael.Key = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.KeySize / 8);
            myRijndael.IV = key.GetBytes(myRijndael.BlockSize / 8);

            // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
            byte[] originalbytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original);
            string decrypted = DecryptStringFromBytes(originalbytes, myRijndael.Key, myRijndael.IV);

            //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted:    " + decrypted);
            return decrypted;
        }
    }
```

**The error comes here:**

[Errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqBi1.png)

Here there full code:

```
static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an RijndaelManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;
    }
```

Greetings

Comment: `i have a problem` You forgot to tell us what that problem is!  It looks like you dumped your code here for someone else to debug or fix your code for you.  Please read [ask] and take the WELCOME [TOUR]

Comment: Wait i will edit it, thanks for your hint.

Comment: If something was really wrong the decryption method would give an exception.  You  are not getting an exception. Either you are not calling the decryption method or you are not printing the actual decrypted results.

Comment: Im calling the method and printing the actual decpryted results too, you can see it on the picture and on the code on the last block.

Comment: I can't see where you attempt to undo what you did with that `StringBuilder` changing the bytes into strings after encryption.

Comment: `i use the same salt and the same password`  but not the same key and IV

Comment: @Plutonix I think has won the prize. You are generating a new key and IV for the decryption process, when it should be the same one you used to encrypt

Comment: @Plutonix - they pull the Key and IV from the salt and password via `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` which is meant to be deterministic. Unless you're seeing something that means that those values aren't being actually used?

Comment: you also create one RijndaelManaged to generate the Key and the IV and then pass that into a method and create another RijndaelManaged and set the key and IV from the first instance onto the second, that just seems odd

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ah yeah sorry, I missed that

Comment: You can never have too many `RijndaelManaged` that's what I say. I add one to every method :)

Comment: my cryptography is a bit rusty, so forgive if this is a stupid question but why then is there a called to myRijndael.GenerateKey(); and myRijndael.GenerateIV(); ??

Comment: myRijndael.GenerateKey(); and myRijndael.GenerateIV(); is not important, i deleted it, thats right. Im just starting with cryptography so i cant follow right, possible that the mistake is so easy, but i dont understand it.

Comment: You'd clean up a lot more if you weren't trying to force the *output* from encryption to be text. You could write the bytes directly to the file (using `WriteAllBytes` instead) and read those bytes directly from the file (using `ReadAllBytes`) and I think that would get over the issue I've highlighted - there's no equivalent to undo `s.Append(item.ToString("X2") + " ");` in your decryption code.

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a good guide on [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). One thing it highlights is the importance of being able to get to the point of being able to say "this line of code does X" and then run that line and confirm that it does in fact do what you said it would do. This is the sort of debugging you need to be doing.

Comment: Yeah but the the wired thing is, when i put a tring in my console, and not a .txt file then it works. I tested, i typed ,,Hello how are you?" and let it encrypt, i copied the encrypted text, then i closed the application, start it new and inserted the encrypted text, and i get as decypred text the following back ,,Hello how are you?"...

Comment: Hi. Note that if you're writing software that encrypts and decrypts data, until you've successfully decrypted data you've encrypted, you cannot say which part it is that is right and which part it is that is wrong. You can have faulty encryption code that doesn't throw an exception but still does it wrong and then even with perfect decryption code you will still get garbage out. So don't be blind to all the possible places the bug might reside.

Comment: Thats an good aspect, thank you.

Comment: I updated my Question, now i get an error, but why? I write the Bytes with File.Writeallbytes and later i read it as a string, dont think that that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are messing with the encrypted text by doing this

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte item in encrypted)
{
    s.Append(item.ToString("X2") + " ");
}
```

As Damien mentioned you should return a byte array from `static string Verschlüsseln(string PW, string original)` and use `File.WriteAllBytes` to write it to file. You can then use `File.ReadAllBytes` to read it from the file and pass a byte[] into you're decrypt method and you don't need to do anything to do with encoding.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it tomorrow and then i will give a feedback, good night!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thank you for your much help, my last error was pretty easy, just a little mistake, here the solution of the part where was the error:

```
                    foreach (var file in d2.GetFiles("*.txt"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(file.FullName, file.Name);
                    string temppfad = file.FullName;
                    byte[] Inhaltsbyte = File.ReadAllBytes(temppfad);
                    string Entschlüsselterinhalt = Entschlüsseln(Password, Inhaltsbyte);
                    File.WriteAllText(temppfad, Entschlüsselterinhalt);
                }
```